# For loop run when I use i but don't when I use something different

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, types

I am a beginner at using javascript. So please don't yell at me if this question looks stupid. I am stuck at it so I asked.
Actually, I am doing a project in which I have to manipulate data a bit but I don't know why it's not working.
this is my code

```
var data = [
  {
    _id: "5fb86715f916fb0011bfad61",
    lastest_volume: 418,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-21T01:02:13.673Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fb9de1df916fb0011ca0ff3",
    lastest_volume: 419,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-22T03:42:21.107Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fbb31e2f916fb0011d13555",
    lastest_volume: 421,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-23T03:52:02.960Z",
  }
]
var re = /-/gi
for (let i in data) {
  data[i].modificationDate = data[i].modificationDate.slice(0, 10);
  data[i].modificationDate = data[i].modificationDate.replace(re, "");
  let j = +i + 1;

  data[i].lastest_volume = data[val].lastest_volume - data[i].lastest_volume;
}
console.log(data);
```

its giving me this error

```
data[i].lastest_volume = data[j].lastest_volume - data[i].lastest_volume;
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastest_volume' of undefined
```

its working when I am using i but didn't work if I use j instead of i

Comment: During third iteration, i=2 and j =3, you are trying to access data[3].latest_volume, where length of your array is only 3 so there won't be data[3].

Comment: And the error doesn't align with the posted code.

Comment: @DaveNewton he has a typo (val instead of j) but the underlying issue is what Raghuraman Kesavan pointed out.

Comment: @nitrin0 Yes, I'm aware (hence the "and")--my point is that the code posted should be the code in question to avoid chasing red herrings.

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "val" in `data[val].lastest_volume`. "val" isn't something that's been defined yet, so that's coming out as `data[undefined]`. I notice also that in the previous line, `let j,` that `j` isn't being used later; I'm guessing you meant to use `data[j]` instead of `[val]`?

<s>There's also an issue with that `j`. The plus sign in `= +i`; javascript doesn't know what to do with that, so that also translates to `let j = undefined + 1`, which will always be 1 no matter how far the for loop has progressed. (You might be thinking of the syntax `i++`, which adds 1 to `i`, but you're not trying to change `i` here, but to set `j`.)</s> Edit: Oops—right, that `+` coerces a string to a number.

Comment: [MDN: JavaScript unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
    _id: "5fb86715f916fb0011bfad61",
    lastest_volume: 418,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-21T01:02:13.673Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fb9de1df916fb0011ca0ff3",
    lastest_volume: 419,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-22T03:42:21.107Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fbb31e2f916fb0011d13555",
    lastest_volume: 421,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-23T03:52:02.960Z",
  }
]
var re = /-/gi
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].modificationDate = data[i].modificationDate.slice(0, 10);
  data[i].modificationDate = data[i].modificationDate.replace(re, "");
  let j = i + 1;



  /*this code changes j to index 0 if j is greater than data.length*/
  let val = (j >= data.length) ? 0 : j;


  data[i].lastest_volume = data[val].lastest_volume - data[i].lastest_volume;
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot better to use map function

```js
let data = [{
    _id: "5fb86715f916fb0011bfad61",
    lastest_volume: 418,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-21T01:02:13.673Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fb9de1df916fb0011ca0ff3",
    lastest_volume: 419,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-22T03:42:21.107Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "5fbb31e2f916fb0011d13555",
    lastest_volume: 421,
    modificationDate: "2020-11-23T03:52:02.960Z",
  }
]
let re = /-/gi;

let result = data.map(function(r, i, arr) {

  r.modificationDate = r.modificationDate.slice(0, 10);
  r.modificationDate = r.modificationDate.replace(re, "");

  let j = i + 1;
  let val = (j >= data.length) ? -1 : j;

  if (val > 0) {
    r.lastest_volume = arr[val].lastest_volume - arr[i].lastest_volume;
  } else {
    r.lastest_volume = 'Last Item';
  }

  return r;
});


console.log(result);
```